# Dbf library -------

Tags: python-3.x

```
I'm trying to create a simple DBF file using the dbf library in Python, but no matter which columns I add, I always receive the same error.
The code used is :
from dbf import Table, Field

def proba():
    structura_campuri = [
        Field('Nume', 'C', 50),
        Field('Varsta', 'N', 3),
        Field('Salariu', 'N', 8, 2)
    ]
    tabel = Table('Exemplu.dbf', structura_campuri)
    tabel.open(mode='w')
    tabel.append(('John Doe', 25, 5000.0))
    tabel.append(('Jane Smith', 30, 6000.0))
    tabel.close()

proba()
```

The code should create a DBF file with the specified table headers; however, it returns an error every time I run it in the form of:

"

```
>>> %Run test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dell\Desktop\programe python\proba\test.py", line 15, in <module>
    proba()
  File "C:\Users\dell\Desktop\programe python\proba\test.py", line 5, in proba
    Field('Nume', 'C', 50),
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311-32\Lib\site-packages\aenum\_enum.py", line 1786, in __call__
    return cls._create_(value, names, module=module, qualname=qualname, type=type, start=start, boundary=boundary)
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311-32\Lib\site-packages\aenum\_enum.py", line 1966, in _create_
    _, first_enum = cls._get_mixins_(class_name, bases)
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311-32\Lib\site-packages\aenum\_enum.py", line 2035, in _get_mixins_
    mcls._check_for_existing_members_(class_name, bases)
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311-32\Lib\site-packages\aenum\_enum.py", line 2021, in _check_for_existing_members_
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: <aenum 'Nume'> cannot extend <aenum 'Field'>
```

Comment: Please add a `python` tag and format your prose and code properly.